# .FindNext() with xlPrevious

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to find all values "O" from bottom to top. I can't use the "normal" find because I'm going to `offset` some values down and `.Find()` will find them again.

The problem is that when i use `.FindNext` after a `.Find()` with `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` it goes back to the top instead of following the direction.

For test purposes I'm using this code:

```
Dim f As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.Cells(7, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(6, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 6).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 7).Value = "O"

Set f = ws.Range("A1:AX50").Find(what:="O", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Debug.Print f.Address
Set f = ws.Range("A1:AX50").FindNext(f)
Debug.Print f.Address
```

It prints `$E$7` and `$E$5`. I was expecting `$E$7` and `$E$6`.

I'm not sure this is the best method to find all values from bottom to top. Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: a) this might be a xlByRows vs xlByColumns issue b) is the second `ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = "O"` a typo?

Comment: @user10735198 a) It needs to be  'xlByRows'  because I want from bottom to top, not from right to left. b) yes it is, I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Range.FindNext method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) is clearly not inheriting the SearchDirection:=xlPrevious argument. You need the base [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with the After:=f argument instead.

```
Dim f As Range, addr As String, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.Cells(7, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(6, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 6).Value = "O"
ws.Cells(5, 7).Value = "O"

With ws.UsedRange.Cells  'Range("A1:AX50")
    Set f = .Find(What:="O", after:=.Cells(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        addr = f.Address(0, 0)
        Do
            Debug.Print f.Address
            Set f = .Find(What:="O", after:=f, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        Loop Until addr = f.Address(0, 0)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I was just about to get to that same conclusion! I guess `.FindNext(f)` is really `.Find(what:=f.Value, after:=f)`.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use .FindPrevious instead of .FindNext